# How to save the keycloak data when running inside docker container?

Tags: docker, keycloak, mount, podman

I run keycloak standalone using a command for [docker](https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-docker) `docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:15.0.2`

How to mount a volume to save the data, after container is stopped?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## For the production:

In the production environment Keycloak should be connected to a [real database (mariadb, mssql, mysql, oracle, postgres)](https://www.keycloak.org/server/db). The data is stored there, thus there is no need to store anything running in the container.

## For the development:

Keycloak comes with its own embedded Java-based relational database called H2.
The data is stored in `/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data/` inside the container.

To start the container with a mounted volume you need:

#### 1. Create a folder with read-write permissions:

```bash
mkdir -m 777 ./keycloak_data
```

#### 2. Start the container with the mounted volume:

```bash
docker run -v ./keycloak_data:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data/ -p 8080:8080  -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:15.0.2
```

Note that if you mount the volume, the `KEYCLOAK_USER` and `KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD` will only be considered by the first start of the container, so **to start the container again** just use:

```bash
docker run -v ./keycloak_data:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data/ -p 8080:8080 quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:15.0.2
```

Comment: From Keycloak doc `The H2 database is not very viable in high concurrency situations`. You should to use external supported DB in real production env, not H2. So this answer is OK only for "dev" env.

Comment: In keycloak 21 (not sure when it changed), the new path to map for development is: ```/opt/keycloak/data/h2```

Answer (score 8):

working `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.7"

volumes:
  keycloak:

services:

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.2
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
    volumes:
      - keycloak:/opt/keycloak/data/
    restart: always
    command:
      - "start-dev"
```

Answer (score 1):

**update 2023:**

based on @mdryden and @Dennis Meissel response, in order to make keycloak persistent for local development, just run the following commands:

```
mkdir -m 777 ./keycloak_data
docker run -p 8080:8080 -v ./keycloak_data:/opt/keycloak/data/h2 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0.3 start-dev
```